# Jenkinsfile, get all modified files in the PR

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I want to have a list of modified files in the PR, I tried a few solutions but I can only have access to the modified files in the last commits pushed to remote.

**Example:**

- Create a PR with 3 commits, a new jenkins job starts;
- The list of modified files includes all files from the 3 commits;
- The build fails, push a new commit with the fix into the PR, a new jenkins jobs starts;
- The list of modified files only includes the files of the new commit;

So, in this example I want to have the list of files from all the new commits in the PR.

**Code:**

```
  def changeLogSets = currentBuild.rawBuild.changeSets
    for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
        def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
        for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
            def entry = entries[j]
            def files = new ArrayList(entry.affectedFiles)
            for (int k = 0; k < files.size(); k++) {
                def file = files[k]
                print file.path 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution using a git command:

```
/**
 * Compares the current branch and target branch and extract the changed files.
 *
 * @return the PR changed files.
 */
def getPRChangelog() {
    return sh(
            script: "git --no-pager diff origin/${params.target} --name-only",
            returnStdout: true
    ).split('\n')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Git Plugin (if you aren't already). Then something like:

```
git diff --name-status $GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT..$GIT_COMMIT > allchanges
```

That will give you the list of all changes since the last successful build.

Comment: This is giving me error `GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT: unbound variable`